# Check if Download Link Works in Email

Tags: javascript, c#, html, azure-blob-storage

I am creating an email that will send out a link to a PDF in an Azure Blob Container. I am also playing a time limit on the link so it will no longer work after 30 days. Here is what my code that creates the azure link and email message looks like:

```
// Establishes a connection with Azure.
            string storageConnection = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("AzureBlobConnectionString");
            CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnection);

            // Gets access to the quote blob container.
            CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("quotes");
            cloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists(BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob);

            // Inserts the pdf into Azure Blob.
            CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("Quote_" + orderId + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd") + ".pdf"); ;
            await cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(report.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat));

            // Creates the 30 day time limit to access the pdf.
            DateTime expirationDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(new TimeSpan(30, 0, 0, 0));
            SharedAccessBlobPolicy sharedAccessBlobPolicy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy();
            sharedAccessBlobPolicy.SharedAccessExpiryTime = expirationDate;
            sharedAccessBlobPolicy.Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read;

            // Creates the uri with the time limit.
            string sharedAccesSignature = cloudBlockBlob.GetSharedAccessSignature(sharedAccessBlobPolicy);
            string uri = cloudBlockBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + sharedAccesSignature;

            StringBuilder messageBody = new StringBuilder();
            messageBody.Append("Your Quote is attached.<br /><br />");
            if (additionalNotes.Replace(" ", "").Length > 0)
            {
                messageBody.Append("Addtional Notes:<br />");
                messageBody.Append(additionalNotes + "<br /><br />");
            }
            messageBody.Append("<a href=\"" + uri + "\" download=\"MyGoogleLogo\">Download Quote PDF</a><br />");
            messageBody.Append("<b>*** Link will expire after 30 days (" + expirationDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + ") ***</b><br /><br />");
            messageBody.Append("<b>Please do not reply back to this email.</b>");
```

Is there a way to redirect the user to a designed error page if they click the link after the time limit?

Comment: Has your problem been solved?  I wonder if my answer will help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set static page in Azure Blobs.

You can refer the [offical document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website-how-to?tabs=azure-portal) to create your download page which contains the logic of time limit. If the link does not expire, download it, and if it expires, jump to your custom error page.

[image]

You can upload your `DownloadPage.html`,and modify code. The value of `uri` set like  `https://pan**storage.blob.core.windows.net/asset-*****-4baf-48a5-9ea1-6cb09319e679/DownloadPage.html?downloadurl=XXXXXXXX&expirationDate=2020-05-22 15:40:30`

```
messageBody.Append("<a href=\"" + uri + "\" download=\"MyGoogleLogo\">Download Quote PDF</a><br />");
```

In the `DownloadPage.html`, you can check the link does not expire by parameter `expirationDate`.

This is just a suggestion, of course, you can also use your own application website for better logic processing.

Comment: Does setting the static website only work for the $web container?

Comment: @Lotzi11 Anyone who knows the URL of this page can access it, not only work for the $web container.

Comment: ok. I got it working and implemented. Thank you for your help.